# Cannot Increase Apache Open Slots

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, webserver

I have a problem on my apache web server with increasing my users. The website not responding when the number of processors reaches 256.

I tried to resolve it by increasing the values ​​of "Server Limit" and "Max Client", but it did not affect the result, knowing that I even rebooted the system to make the effect work, but to no avail.

Note: I also use php-fpm.

**My system inf**

```
  CPU:  [4x] 2438.54Mhz Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2120 CPU @ 3.30GHz (3072 KB Cache)
    System Memory:  15858.24 MB
```

**My web Server Status:**

```
Server load: 0.82 0.88 0.85
Total accesses: 64206 - Total Traffic: 1.0 GB - Total Duration: 61910116
CPU Usage: u9.62 s6.62 cu121.01 cs41.14 - 4.83% CPU load
17.4 requests/sec - 295.4 kB/second - 17.0 kB/request - 964.242 ms/request
119 requests currently being processed, 9 idle workers

RKCWKRRKKRKK_WKRRRCKRKWKKKRRRKKCKKKKCRWKRKKKKR._RKKRCKKKWCKRKRKR
KKKK_KKKKR_KRW_W_KRKRKKK.R._.K.RKKKR.RRRRW.KR.KC.RR.K.RWR.K_KKKK
K.K.RKK...CKK_...R...........KW.................................
................................................................
```

**My server information**

```
Server Version: Apache/2.4.41
Timeouts: connection: 300    keep-alive: 10
MPM Name: prefork
MPM Information: Max Daemons: 256 Threaded: no Forked: yes
Server Architecture: 64-bit
```

I did not understand what is Max Daemon is it the same Max Client?

**Prefork MPM settings**

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers       8
MinSpareServers   10
MaxSpareServers   20
ServerLimit      2500
MaxRequestWorkers       2000
MaxConnectionsPerChild  10000
</IfModule>
```

[My Web Server Clients Graph At the problem time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yi5Ix.jpg)

Thank you!